# Python version 3.9 does not support match statements

Tags: python, python-3.9

I installed Python on a new computer and unfortunately I get an error message from a code that I had been using for quite some time. It is about the 'match' statement. Here is the code:

```
import os

def save(df, filepath):
    dir, filename = os.path.split(filepath)
    os.makedirs(dir, exist_ok=True)
    _, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    match ext:
        case ".pkl":
            df.to_pickle(filepath)
        case ".csv":
            df.to_csv(filepath)
        case _:
            raise NotImplementedError(f"Saving as {ext}-files not implemented.")
```

Now my question is, how can I tackle the problem of "Python version 3.9 does not support match statements"?

Comment: How did you install Python?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't update your installed Python version?

Comment: @Cobra: Thanks Cobra for your comment. Unforunately I can't update the Python interpreter to 3.10 in PyCharm. When doing so, I get an error message which tells me that I should download Python manually. I have had bad experience trying to install Python manually this is why I don't necessarily want to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or just `if` and `elif`.

```py
import os

def save(df, filepath):
    dir, filename = os.path.split(filepath)
    os.makedirs(dir, exist_ok=True)
    _, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    if ext == ".pkl":
        df.to_pickle(filepath)
    elif ext == ".csv":
        df.to_csv(filepath)
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError(f"Saving as {ext}-files not implemented.")
```

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer: upgrade to Python 3.10.

If you cannot upgrade, then you can use a Python dictionary as alternative:

```py
MATCH = {
    '.pkl': df.to_pickle
    '.csv': df.to_csv
}

_, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)

try:
    MATCH[ext](filepath)
except KeyError:
    raise NotImplementedError(f"Saving as {ext}-files not implemented.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Match statements are a feature of Python 3.10. You'd do best by upgrading to 3.10 or 3.11.

https://monovm.com/blog/how-to-update-python-version/

Comment: Thanks Teyras for your answer. Unfortunately I can't update the Python Interpreter (see comment above under my question).

Comment: It is unhelpful to say "you should just upgrade" when prior versions are not yet EOL and there are strong reasons for some to use them.

Comment: @jakebeal I never said that. I just supplied information about the version required to get acesss to the feature OP wanted to use. It's either that or modifying the code, and deciding which tradeoff to make is up to the OP.

Comment: @Teyras "It's either that or modifying the code": and your answer does not present that option, either internally or by reference to elsewhere. For this reason, I find it unhelpful and have down-voted you. If you improved the answer to better match what is in your comment, I would retract that downvote.